# IIS Redirect Rule to redirect all subdomain traffic

Tags: iis, regex

I have this rewrite rule defined in the web.config file on my site:

```
<rule name="RedirectWwwToNonWww" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The rule will redirect as follows:

- From: `www.example.com/test`
- To: `example.com/test`

The rule works fine, however, I would like to change the rule so that all subdomains redirect to the main site - e.g. `this.example.com/test` or `something.example.com/test` but I am struggling to work out how to change the regular expression to achieve that.

I have tried:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(*\.)(.*)$" />
```

And:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(*)(.*)$" />
```

But neither work, because I am clearly doing something wrong.

I got a bit further, with:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([^.]+)(.*)$" />
```

But when I test the RegEx in IIS, I end up with:

- From: `something.example.com/test`
- To: `.example.com/test`

So that removes the subdomain before `example.com` but leaves behind the single `.` in front of example.com, so I can't work out how to remove that remaining `.`.

How can I achieve the redirect?

Thanks

Comment: You'd better chat with one of modern AIs to get the regular expression you wanted, where you can feed more details like the actual domains you wanted to support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<rule name="redirect subdomain" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$"/> 
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify the rewrite rule to redirect all subdomains to the main site (example.com), you can update the regular expression pattern in the condition. Here's the modified rule:

```
`<rule name="RedirectSubdomainsToMainSite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www\.)(.*)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>`
```